# SQL left join with SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join

I need to join one table with another, where for each type of group in left table i got sum of this value types in second table, where  group_type = 4.
I tried following:

```
SELECT *
FROM orbiting_group_types ogt
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT SUM(val)
 FROM report_orbiting_vals  rov
 ORDER by TYPE
 WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 4)
ON ogt.id = rov.orbiting_group_type_id
```

However it throw me an error -

```
 syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 8:  WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 4)
```

What did i miss?

Comment: The `ORDER by` should go after the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM orbiting_group_types ogt
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT SUM(val)
FROM report_orbiting_vals  subrov
WHERE subrov.orbiting_group_type_id = 4
//ORDER by TYPE
) rov
ON ogt.id = rov.orbiting_group_type_id
```

1) You should name your subqueries to reference them. You can't make a reference from the outside of the subquery to the inside.

2) TYPE doesn't sound like a column name

3) ORDER BY goes after WHERE, always.

Comment: it actually should be SELECT *
FROM orbiting_group_types ogt
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT SUM(val), orbiting_group_type_id
FROM report_orbiting_vals  subrov
WHERE subrov.orbiting_group_type_id = 4
GROUP by orbiting_group_type_id) rov
ON ogt.id = rov.orbiting_group_type_id

Answer (score 4):

You didn't alias your subquery and your subquery doesn't select the field you're joining on in the main query. As other mentioned the `order by` in a subquery won't work.

I suspect you're looking for a result along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM orbiting_group_types ogt
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT SUM(val), orbiting_group_type_id
 FROM report_orbiting_vals  rov
 WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 4
group by orbiting_group_type_id) as rov
ON ogt.id = rov.orbiting_group_type_id
```

Notice `as rov`, `group by`, the second column in the select of your subquery and the removal of `order by`.

Comment: thank you, but for not it show me - ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 7:  WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 4) as rov
         ^

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban You're right, the `WHERE` should preceed `GROUP BY`, changed it accordingly. Could not test the `SQL` since I don't have the corresponding table definitions. Hopefully this version will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

In general `order by` clause must come after the `where` clause. Also, `order by` is meaningless in a sub query - I suspect you mean `group by` in this case.

Comment: This only handles 1 of the 3 errors in the question.